# Python: How do I convert time.strftime to display UTC instead of Local timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, date-conversion

I am trying to open a file whose name is changed based on UTC datetime.

I use the following to grab the filename:

```
datetoday = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
print datetoday
filename = "C:\Users\Downloads\filename-%s.csv" % datetoday
inputfile = open(filename)
```

The issue is that this is printing the filename in local (EST) timezone and not in the UTC which I want.

Is there a way to convert time.strftime() to display UTC timezone and not local?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the contents of `time`?

Comment: I imported a library called time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of:

```
import time
datetoday = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

try:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetoday = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime
datetoday = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")

Suggested by Jack worked!